# How/when do I free the memory of a C string created by Go code?

Tags: go, cgo

Here is my code:

**helloworld.go**:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() *C.char {
    cs := C.CString("Hello World!")
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    return cs
}

func main() {}
```

**node-helloworld.cc**:

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <node.h>
#include <string>

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, HelloWorld()));
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(helloworld, init)

}
```

When I execute the code I get:

�Oc

or

��#

or

���

etc

It's actually random. I seem to be getting something different every time.

It might be that I am passing *char array* from `HelloWorld()` method.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

When I remove:

```
C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
```

I get the good string. And not random characters.

But I need `C.free` to free the memory. It is recommended here: https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo

> The call to C.CString returns a pointer to the start of the char
>   array, so before the function exits we convert it to an unsafe.Pointer
>   and release the memory allocation with C.free.

I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: I am not familiar with go, but return a freed `cs` looks suspicious to me

Comment: `cs` is just a variable. Actually, I just remembered that if I remove: `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))` I actually get the whole string. The issue now is that I am not clearing the memory like it is recommended here: https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo

Comment: Please don't apply what's written there without thinking through what happens in the provided example. There, they take a Go string, convert it to a C string—which calls `C.malloc()` internally,—then pass that C string to the `C.fputs()` function which *reads that memory and outputs the characters from it to the standard output stream. After that call returns, that memory can be considered to be "done with", and hence needs to be freed.

Comment: In other words, no transfer of ownership has happened: we have allocated the memory and then called a function which merely read from it, so when it exited, we still own that memory region and since it's not needed anymore, we have to free it. Your own code is completely different in this regard: you callocate memory in your Go code and *want to transfer this memory block to some other code* for it to further deal with it *however it sees fit.* This is a clear transfer of ownership, so your Node code has to be in charge of freeing that memory block.

Comment: Let me recap: don't blindly apply whatever you read somewhere: try to think *why* the code does whatever it does; don't just try to squeeze a pattern like "Okay, all calls to `C.CString()` and `C.free()` have to come in pairs for whatever reason". When there's no garbage collection (this is C), at any given time, any allocated memory region is "owned" by some part of the running code. In some languages (say, Rust) this is explicit; in C, it's implicit, so always think through which code has to be in charge of each allocated memory block.

Answer (score 5):

The linked example frees the allocated memory because no other code needs it.

If your Go function needs to return some allocated memory so that it can be used by some C code then the Go function should not call C.free, instead the C code that uses that memory should be responsible for freeing it after it does not need it anymore.

Arbitrary example:

[cgo/test/issue20910.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ee714947c511715c752179fe738a45045ffa205c/misc/cgo/test/issue20910.go)

[cgo/test/issue20910.c](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ee714947c511715c752179fe738a45045ffa205c/misc/cgo/test/issue20910.c)